# Code to get MAC address seems to corrupt memory, but only in Release build, not Debug build

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

Following code, when used in an Embarcadero C++ Builder 2009, 'Release' build, appears to be corrupting memory:

```
String MyCode::MacAddress(bool Dashes, DWORD *Index)
{
// Dashes to build the string with dashes or not: 00-14-22-01-23-45 vs. 001422012345

// Index is Input and Output.
// If NULL or Index==0 the first Mac address is requested.
// If > 0 that mac address is requested (0 based index)
// The return value, if !NULL, is always the count of available mac addresses

String Address ;

DWORD (*MyGetAdaptersInfo)(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen) = NULL ;
HMODULE khand = NULL ;
DWORD GetIndex = (Index)?(*Index):(0) ;
if (Index) *Index = 0 ;

if (!khand)
    {
    khand = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Iphlpapi.dll")) ;

    if (khand)
        {
        MyGetAdaptersInfo = (DWORD (*)(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen)) GetProcAddress(khand, "GetAdaptersInfo") ;
        }
    }

if (MyGetAdaptersInfo)
    {
    DWORD MacBufLen = 0 ;
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO IPInfo ;
    MyGetAdaptersInfo(&IPInfo, &MacBufLen) ;
    if (MacBufLen)
        {
        BYTE *Buffer = new BYTE[MacBufLen] ;
        if (Buffer)
            {
            IP_ADAPTER_INFO *IPInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)Buffer ;
            if (MyGetAdaptersInfo(IPInfo, &MacBufLen) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                DWORD Cnt = (MacBufLen / sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)) ;
                if (Index) *Index = Cnt ;
                if (GetIndex < Cnt)
                    {
                    IPInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*) &Buffer[(GetIndex * sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO))] ;
                    for (DWORD x = 0 ; x < IPInfo->AddressLength ; x++)
                        {
                        if (!Dashes || x == (IPInfo->AddressLength - 1))
                            {
                            Address += String().sprintf(L"%.2X", (int)IPInfo->Address[x]) ;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            Address += String().sprintf(L"%.2X-", (int)IPInfo->Address[x]) ;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        delete[] Buffer ;
        }
    }

FreeLibrary(khand) ;

return Address ;
}
```

Can you see what I'm currently unable to see ?

I have been using this code for a while now in debug builds without issues.  So I never doubted its correct functioning.  But now that I built a release version, using Embarcadero c++ Builder 2009, it appears to be corrupting memory of other functionality that is called afterwards, ultimately leading to an exception error.

When I remove the MacAddress() call from the code, all works like a charm again.

In Debug mode CodeGuard never triggered either.

Your input appreciated

Comment: Calling convention is missing. That's a `__stdcall` (or `WINAPI` if you prefer the win32 macros) function.

Comment: I notice this line:   
if (!khand)   
Seems unnecessary, since khand is initialized to NULL.   
Are you calling this function recursively ?

Comment: [What can go wrong when you mismatch the calling convention?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043)

Comment: What is the need for calling this function dynamically? What version of the OS are you trying to support that does not include it?

Comment: The code is also declaring two separate `IPInfo` variables.  The first one is unnecessary and should be removed. The first call to `MyGetAdaptersInfo()` should be using `NULL` instead of `&IPInfo`.

Comment: Thanks Guys.  I'll check Remy's code in about an hour from and I know it will solve all problems.  Of course ... the calling convention !

Comment: @SmittyBoy, reused some older code for different function, this was left behind.

Comment: @Code Gray, I suppose dynamic was not needed here indeed, since 2K is the minimum supported OS.

Comment: @Remy, I recall having some issues and seeing it work by changing NULL to `IPInfo` in the debug build.  I should have stopped right there and investigated properly but I was working against the clock that day.  It always appeared to work properly after that so I did not revisit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not declaring a calling convention for your `MyGetAdaptersInfo` variable, so the compiler's default (usually `__cdecl`) is used.  But the `GetAdaptersInfo()` function (as well as the majority of the Win32 API) uses the `__stdcall` calling convention, so you need to include that in your declaration.

Also, you should not be relying on `sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)`, either.  Its size can change from one OS version to another, and there is no option to know what size a given version is actually using.  `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` is implemented as a linked list (even if it is allocated as a single contiguous memory buffer), you need to walk the list correctly using the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO::Next` field.

Try something more like this:

```
String MyCode::MacAddress(bool Dashes, DWORD *Index)
{
    // Dashes to build the string with dashes or not: 00-14-22-01-23-45 vs. 001422012345

    // Index is Input and Output.
    // If NULL or Index==0 the first Mac address is requested.
    // If > 0 that mac address is requested (0 based index)
    // The return value, if !NULL, is always the count of available mac addresses

    String Address;

    typedef DWORD (WINAPI *LPFN_GetAdaptersInfo)(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO, PULONG);

    DWORD GetIndex = (Index) ? *Index : 0;
    if (Index) *Index = 0;

    HMODULE khand = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Iphlpapi.dll"));
    if (khand)
    {
        LPFN_GetAdaptersInfo MyGetAdaptersInfo = (LPFN_GetAdaptersInfo) GetProcAddress(khand, "GetAdaptersInfo");
        if (MyGetAdaptersInfo)
        {
            DWORD MacBufLen = 0;
            if ((MyGetAdaptersInfo(NULL, &MacBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
                && (MacBufLen > 0))
            {
                DynamicArray<BYTE> Buffer; // or std::vector<BYTE>
                Buffer.Length = MacBufLen;

                PIP_ADAPTER_INFO IPInfo = (PIP_ADAPTER_INFO) &Buffer[0];
                if (MyGetAdaptersInfo(IPInfo, &MacBufLen) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    DWORD Cnt = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if (GetIndex == Cnt)
                        {
                            for (DWORD x = 0; x < IPInfo->AddressLength; ++x)
                            {
                                if (!Dashes || (x == (IPInfo->AddressLength - 1)))
                                {
                                    Address += String().sprintf(L"%.2X", (int) IPInfo->Address[x]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Address += String().sprintf(L"%.2X-", (int) IPInfo->Address[x]) ;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ++Cnt;
                        IPInfo = IPInfo->Next;
                    }
                    while (IPInfo != NULL);

                    if (Index) *Index = Cnt;
                }
            }
        }

        FreeLibrary(khand);
    }

    return Address;
}
```